# Error on custom method "... must return a result of type double"

Tags: java, methods

The goal of the program is to calculate either the volume,surface area, area or circumference given a user input. I am still trying to figure out on how i would loop certain things, but here is my real problem:

I try and run the program but I get the error shown above, also with the return statements where would I place an ending message telling the user the final information he wishes to know (The things the program calculated).

An answer to my main problem "... must return a result of type double" would be much appreciated, any help towards other things I mentioned here would also go a long way.

Also the properly formatted code thing is extreme annoying, I am not sure of what it means by telling me to space it out by 4 spaces, whenever I do it and it works, someone always edits it, this is very counter-intuitive.

```
import java.io.*;
public class circlemethods
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
      BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
      String numInput;  
      String reqInput;
      int num;
      int numInt = 0;
      System.out.println("This program will ask for a given user radius, then proceed to calculate the req");
      System.out.println("The program will use several methods to achieve this, all calling back to the main method");
      System.out.println("Press any key to continue");
      numInput = myInput.readLine();
      System.out.println("First, what would you like to calculate?");
      System.out.println("Enter '1' for Circumference, '2' for area, '3' for volume, or '4' for surface area");
      reqInput = myInput.readLine();
      numInt = Integer.parseInt (reqInput);
      System.out.println("Now enter the radius of the required shape");
      numInput = myInput.readLine();
      num = Integer.parseInt (numInput); 
    }
    public static  double circumference(double volume, double surfacearea, double area,  double radius) throws IOException {
      int numInt = 0;
      int num = 0;
      double circumference;
      for (int i = 0; i < volume ; i++) {
        if (numInt == 1)
        {
          System.out.println("You chose to calculate circumference, given the radius :"+ num );
          circumference = (3.14) * (2) * (num);
          return  circumference;
        }
        if (numInt == 2)
        {
          System.out.println("You chose to calculate area, given the radius:" + num);
          area = (3.14)*(num)*(num);
          return area;
        }
        if (numInt == 3)
        {
          System.out.println("You chose to calculate volume, given the radius:" + num);
          volume = 4/3 * (3.14)*(num)*(3)*(3)*(3);
          return volume;
        }      
        if (numInt == 4)
        {
          System.out.println("You chose to calculate surface area, given the radius:" + num);
          surfacearea = 4*(3.14)*(num)*(2)*(2);
          return surfacearea;
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Invalid entry, please restart the program");  
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What will your `circumference()` metohd return if the argument `volume` is negative? ;)

Comment: It obviously does not pay off for compiler writers to give very clear error messages! What exactly could be possibly misunderstood in "circumference() must return a double value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should always return a double.
Try something like this:

```
...

 if (numInt == 4)
 {
   System.out.println("You chose to calculate surface area, given the radius:" + num);
   surfacearea = 4*(3.14)*(num)*(2)*(2);
   return surfacearea;
 }

 else
 {
   return -1;
 }
```

where the caller of the method checks for the result,
if it is smaller than 0, it knows it failed and than prints:

```
 System.out.println("Invalid entry, please restart the program");
```

**EDIT:**

and if the loop isn't entered at all, than also the method should return -1

Comment: this alone won't fix it. The loop might be skipped completely.

Comment: right, didn't read the all code, it was tiring :) if the loop isn't entered should still return -1. I've corrected my answer. thanks